# como configurar reverse proxy nginx odoo ERP en docker

Tags: docker, nginx, odoo

tengo un contenedor docker con odoo en el puerto 8069 y otro contenedor docker con postgres en el puerto 5432, estoy montando otro contenedor con nginx ya que el contenedor de odoo debe manejar dos bases de datos (db1-mydomain-com, db2-mydomain-com) y los respectivos dominios son db1.mydomain.com y db2.mydomain.com

el problema esta en que no estoy conciente de como configurar esto correctamente... para que se enrute correctamente, ya que no tengo ni idea como funciona nginx. Lo que e hecho es lo siguiente:

**Docker File:**

```
FROM nginx
MAINTAINER Camptocamp
ADD
https://github.com/kelseyhightower/confd/releases/download/v0.11.0/confd-0.11.0-linux-amd64 /usr/local/bin/confd
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/confd

RUN mkdir -p /etc/confd/{conf.d,templates}
COPY conf.d /etc/confd/conf.d
COPY templates /etc/confd/templates
COPY docker-entrypoint.sh /docker-entrypoint.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["/docker-entrypoint.sh"]

ENV NGX_ODOO_HOST=odoo

CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

**docker-compose:**

```
version: '3'
services:
  nginx:
      build:
          context: ./
          dockerfile: Dockerfile
      ports:
        - "80:80"
      volumes:
        - ./code:/code
        - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes encontrar un ejemplo en este repositorio que te enlazo en el conecto un php-fpm con nginx. https://github.com/Sermanes/Nginx-symfony-https

Pero para que quede resuelta tu duda lo que debes hacer es crear un upstream dentro de nginx.conf con la dirección de tu odoo

```
    # Defined odoo servers
    upstream odoo {
        server odoo:8069;
    }
```

y luego si quieres ya un proxy o quieres usar nginx como servidor dentro de tu archivo de configurador le pones

```
fastcgi_pass odoo;
```

o

```
proxy_pass odoo;
```

Más información dentro de Nginx http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html